# Receiving JSON-Data via http: empty response

Tags: json, http, typescript, angular

I'm new to Angular2 and somehow it's really hard to me to understand how http works in Angular2. I made a simple component which should display a json response. It doesn't work and I have no idea why. I checked many tutorials and tried it with promises as well as observables. Doesn't work. I just can't get the data of the response.

My code:

```
  private doAction() {
    this.doHttpRequest().subscribe(
      data => this.content = data
    );
    this.content = JSON.stringify(this.content);
  }

  private doHttpRequest() {
    return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

this.content is bind to my template. When I click a button to start doAction() for a second I see "" in the template, after another second [object Object]

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior

```
  private doAction() {
    // schedule HTTP call to server and subscribe to get notified when data arrives
    this.doHttpRequest().subscribe(
      // gets called by the observable when the response from the server aarives
      data => this.content = data
    );
    // execute immediately before the call to the server was even sent
    this.content = JSON.stringify(this.content);
  }
```

To fix it change it to

```
  private doAction() {
    this.doHttpRequest().subscribe(
      data => {
        //this.content = data;
        this.content = data.json());
      });
    );
  }
```

If you want code to be executed after data arrived, then you need to move it inside the `subscribe(...)` callback.

Answer (score 0):

Since http requests are asynchron you have to put all your logic depending on the results of the http call in the `subscribe()` callback like this:

```
private doAction() {
  this.doHttpRequest().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.content = data;
      // any more logic must sit in here
    }
  );
}

private doHttpRequest() {
  return this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                .map(res => res.json());
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Http call is returning data since it shows "[object Object]" in template. If you want to see the json data in template you can use the json pipe as below.

{{content | json}}

PS: No need of "this.content = JSON.stringify(this.content);" in your code.